# Export to CSV | DefaultLinkType value of all the sites in Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, csv, defaultlinktype

Is there any SharePoint Online PowerShell script available to export the value of "DefaultLinkType" of all the sites in Tenant to a CSV?

I am not able to find one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ready-made PowerShell script for your requirement. But, I will help you to build this script on your own.

**Get `DefaultLinkType` property of a SharePoint site**:

If you want to get the 
`DefaultLinkType` property of a SharePoint site then you can use:

```
$site = Get-SPOSite -Identity https://spexplorer.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect -Detailed
$site.DefaultSharingLinkType
```

**Get all sites in tenant**:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
```

So you can use the for loop like below to get the site details:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant-name>-admin.sharepoint.com

$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    $siteDetailed = Get-SPOSite $site.Url -Detailed 
    $siteDetailed.DefaultSharingLinkType
}
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/export-list-items-to-csv-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html) link as a reference to export data to CSV.

Comment: Have you tried this? is it working for you??

Comment: Hi @George, does this answers your question? If Yes, please upvote and accept it as an answer so that it will not be shown in unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

Demo code for your reference:

```
Connect-SPOService
Get-SPOSite | Select @{ L = "url"; E = { $_.url } }, @{ L = "DefaultLinkType"; E = { $_.DefaultSharingLinkType } } | Export-Csv -Path c:\export.csv
```